# How context works when passing it with a style object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have the following code:

```
const getStyle = context => ({
  fontWeight: "bold",
  color: context.color,
})
```

What I want to know is how the `context` on the argument of the `getStyle` arrow function is passed down to the `Greeting` arrow function and how does that affect the color properties of my object?

```
const Greeting = (props, context) =>
  <div style={getStyle(context)}>{props.name}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Greeting` is a function. It takes two arguments. The second one is named `context`

It returns a div. The value of the style attribute is the return value of calling `getStyle` with one argument the value of which is the value of the `context` argument.

`getStyle` is another function. It takes one argument. That argument is also called `context`.

So the value is whatever you pass as the second argument when you call `Greeting`.